# Acer Aspire Says no bootable device

Tags: windows

My Acer aspire says there was a problem with the restart when I try to restart it then says there is no bootable device when it try’s to boot up I have checked my bios and I have unhooked the battery I have a back up on usb but it won’t even respond to that

Answer (score 0):

You may receive the error "No Bootable Device" if your computer does not detect a hard drive, solid state drive, or other bootable drive to load the operating system. This can sometimes be caused by a change to settings in your BIOS or UEFI. Use the following steps to resolve this situation:

Hold the power-button for 5 seconds to power off the device.
Power on the system. As soon as the first logo screen appears, immediately press the F2 key, or the DEL key if you have a desktop, to enter the BIOS.
Press F9 and then ENTER to load the default configuration. Press F10 to save your changes, and restart the system. Select Yes and press ENTER to confirm.
Your system should boot up normally, If you are still experiencing a problem, please contact Acer support for further assistance.

[Acer Support](http://us.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/support)

Credit [Acer Community](https://community.acer.com/en/kb/articles/94-no-bootable-device-error-message)
[Acer-Blayn](https://community.acer.com/en/profile/Acer-Blayn)